# C# Check if any int in list matches any int in another list

Tags: c#, list

I apologize if this is an obvious question, but I cannot find the answer.

Say I have the following:

```
var list1 = new List<int>{1,2,3};
var list2 = new List<int>{3,5,6};
```

How can I see if ANY element of list1 is contained in list2? So in this case I want to return true because 3 is in both.

Performing nested loops will not work for me, so it would be ideal if there was a:

```
list1.HasElementIn(list2);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it produces intersection of both sequences. If intersection is not empty, then there some item which exists in both sequences:

```
bool isAnyItemInBothLists = list1.Intersect(list2).Any();
```

One thing to note - thus Intersect is a [deferred streaming operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882641.aspx), then you will get result as soon as any common item will be found. So, you don't need to wait until complete intersection will be computed.

Comment: You rock... I didn't know about Intersect

Comment: So simple. I like it.

Comment: @netorious but how lists related to LINQ to SQL? You clearly specified that you have two lists and even provided sample

Comment: I apologize, I was looking at my problem from the wrong angle. Thanks for your help!